# how to DRY up (remove redundancy) from this css class selector declaration?

Tags: css, optimization, dry, redundancy

I have:

```
    .sketch_img_thumb_box .title{
      opacity: 0.1;
    }
    .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover .title{
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .sketch_img_thumb_box .artist{
      opacity: 0.1;
    }
    .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover .artist{
      opacity: 1;
    }


    .sketch_img_thumb_box .rating_bar {
      opacity: 0.1;
    }
    .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover .rating_bar  {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

I took it down to:

```
  .sketch_img_thumb_box .title, .sketch_img_thumb_box .artist, .sketch_img_thumb_box .rating_bar{
     opacity: 0.1;
 }
  .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover .title, .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover .artist,   .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover .rating_bar{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Can we optimize further?

Comment: show us the html as well to see how to best tackle this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write like this

css:

```
.sketch_img_thumb_box{
         opacity: 0.1;
     }
    .sketch_img_thumb_box:hover{
         opacity: 1;
     }
```

html:

```
<div class="sketch_img_thumb_box">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="artist"></div>
  <div class="rating_bar"></div>
</div>
```

because if you give `opacity` the `parent` then `children` automatically get the opacity.

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/axuxT/4/

& If there are others `children` which you didn't want to give `opacity` then write this:

```
.no_bar{width:50px;height:50px;margin:5px;}
.sketch_img_thumb_box > *{opacity:0.1;display:inline-block;}
.sketch_img_thumb_box:hover > *{opacity:1}
.no_bar{background:black;opacity:1}
```

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/RqP6p/